# present UITableViewController the door cell TableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want `SelectRow` open `tableview` without **storyboard** ??

`tableview` without **storyboard**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let main = UITableViewController()
        let color = UIColor.yellow
        main.view.backgroundColor = color

        self.present(main, animated: true)

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)


            let name = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

            return cell

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't nest the functions

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let main = UITableViewController()
        let color = UIColor.yellow
        main.view.backgroundColor = color

        self.present(main, animated: true)
    }
 }


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) 

    let name = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    // use name here

    return cell

 }
```